# ReferenceError: require is not defined. Использование import и require

Tags: javascript, node.js, веб-программирование, gulp, require

Есть код файла reset.js

```js
/*import {
    deleteAsync
} from "del"*/

const del = require('del');

export const reset = () => {
    async () => {
        const deletedPaths = await del(app.path.clean);
     
        // console.log('Deleted files and directories:\n', deletedPaths.join('\n'));
    }   
    
    // deleteAsync(app.path.clean)
}
```

Выдает ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как устранить ошибку.

1. Закомментировал `"type": "module"` в package.json

```js
    {
      "name": "nft-landing",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "gulpfile.js",
       // "type": "module",
      "scripts": {
        "dev": "gulp",
        "build": "gulp build --build",
        "svgSprive": "gulp svgSprive",
        "zip": "gulp deployZIP --build",
        "deploy": "gulp deployFTP --build"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "devDependencies": {
        "aos": "^2.3.4",
        "browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
        "del": "^5.1.0",
        "gulp": "^4.0.1",
        "gulp-autoprefixer": "^7.0.1",
        "gulp-clean-css": "^4.2.0",
        "gulp-file-include": "^2.1.1",
        "gulp-fonter": "^0.3.0",
        "gulp-group-css-media-queries": "^1.2.2",
        "gulp-if": "^3.0.0",
        "gulp-imagemin": "^7.1.0",
        "gulp-newer": "^1.4.0",
        "gulp-notify": "^3.2.0",
        "gulp-plumber": "^1.2.1",
        "gulp-rename": "^2.0.0",
        "gulp-replace": "^1.0.0",
        "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
        "gulp-svg-sprite": "^1.5.0",
        "gulp-ttf2woff2": "^3.0.0",
        "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
        "gulp-version-number": "^0.2.4",
        "gulp-webp": "^4.0.1",
        "gulp-webp-html-nosvg": "^1.0.0",
        "gulp-webpcss": "^1.1.1",
        "gulp-zip": "^5.0.1",
        "sass": "^1.26.0",
        "swiper": "^5.2.1",
        "vinyl-ftp": "^0.6.1",
        "webp-converter": "^2.2.3",
        "webpack": "^4.41.5",
        "webpack-stream": "^5.2.1"
      }
    }
```

и получил в результате ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. А если вообще удалить `"type": "module"` из package.json, то получаю следующие ошибки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Главный файл `gulpfile.js` имеет вид

```
import gulp from "gulp";
import {path} from "./gulp/config/path.js";
import {plugins} from "./gulp/config/plugins.js";

global.app = {
    isBuild: process.argv.includes('--build'),
    isDev: !process.argv.includes('--build'),
    path: path,
    gulp: gulp,
    plugins: plugins
}

// Имрорт задач
import {copy} from "./gulp/tasks/copy.js";
import {reset} from "./gulp/tasks/reset.js";
import {html} from "./gulp/tasks/html.js";
import {server} from "./gulp/tasks/server.js";
import {scss} from "./gulp/tasks/scss.js";
import {js} from "./gulp/tasks/js.js";
import {images} from "./gulp/tasks/images.js";
import {otfToTtf, ttfToWoff, fontsStyle} from "./gulp/tasks/fonts.js";
import {svgSprive} from "./gulp/tasks/svgSprive.js";
import {zip} from "./gulp/tasks/zip.js";
import {ftp} from "./gulp/tasks/ftp.js";


function watcher() {
    gulp.watch(path.watch.files, copy);
    gulp.watch(path.watch.html, html);
    gulp.watch(path.watch.scss, scss);
    gulp.watch(path.watch.js, js);
    gulp.watch(path.watch.images, images);
}

export {svgSprive}

const fonts = gulp.series(otfToTtf, ttfToWoff, fontsStyle);

const mainTasks = gulp.series(fonts, gulp.parallel(copy, html, scss, js, images));

const dev = gulp.series(reset, mainTasks, gulp.parallel(watcher, server));
const build = gulp.series(reset, mainTasks, svgSprive);
const deployZIP = gulp.series(reset, mainTasks, zip);
const deployFTP = gulp.series(reset, mainTasks, ftp);

export {dev}
export {build}
export {deployZIP}
export {deployFTP}

gulp.task('default', dev);
```

3. Если я в файле reset.js использую

```js
    export const reset = () => {
        async () => {
            const deletedPaths = await del(app.path.clean);
         
            // console.log('Deleted files and directories:\n', deletedPaths.join('\n'));
        }   
        
        // deleteAsync(app.path.clean)
    }
```

то как я должен оформлять в gulpfile.js

```
import {reset} from "./gulp/tasks/reset.js";
```

Что я должен использовать вместо `import {reset} from "./gulp/tasks/reset.js"`(какой оператор, какая синтаксическая конструкция)?

Comment: удалите `"type": "module"` в package.json

Comment: @nörbörnën обновил вопрос.

Comment: Так вы определитесь, используете вы import или require, потому что у вас в одном файле - одно, а в другом - другое

Comment: @Александр а нельзя оба оператора использовать в разных файлах? Просто к примеру в синтаксисе del 5.1.0 используется require, а в других модулях import.